# Run pre-commit hook on all pushed files

Tags: git, pre-commit-hook, pre-commit, pre-commit.com

The basic version of my setup is to have [pre-commit](https://github.com/pre-commit/pre-commit) run a code linter. However I find it too long / inconvenient when it checks/rejects individual commits, instead I'd like to run it once I try to push my code to the remote / CI. I found that I can configure stages, so I decided to put only push stage as default for all my hooks. However, it ends up just letting the non-linted code be pushed. Perhaps it's because it doesn't recognize this code as "changed", as it runs on subset of all files?

Here is my pre-commit config:

```yaml
default_stages: [push]
repos:
-   repo: https://github.com/ambv/black
    rev: 19.10b0
    hooks:
    - id: black
      language_version: python3
```

If it's technically impossible to run it only on the files I'm changing with this push, can I just run it on all files somehow?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you need to make sure you `install` pre-commit for whatever stage you're using

for example from the [pre-commit during push](https://pre-commit.com/#pre-commit-during-push) docs:

> To use pre-push hooks with pre-commit, run:
>
> ```
> $ pre-commit install --hook-type pre-push
> pre-commit installed at .git/hooks/pre-push
> ```

---

disclaimer: I created pre-commit

Comment: I'm surprised it's not installed there by default given that config determines if there's anything to do or not. Thanks for explaining.

Comment: the `default_stages` you set only overrides tools which don't set `stages` explicitly ([as documented](https://pre-commit.com/#top_level-default_stages))